# unexpected '[', como resolver?

Tags: php

Estou com esse erro na linha 38, o código esta desse jeito

```
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 38
```

O código:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array_filter(
            [
                'email' -> $this->getEmail()
            ]

        );
    }
```

acho que talvez seja incompatibilidade com servidor, pois no meu localhost funciona, o PHP do servidor e o 5.4, alguém sabe como faço pra resolver

Comment: A notação `[]` para *arrays* foi adicionada justamente na versão 5.4, então não deveria ser problema; aliado a isso, não existe no PHP algo como `->`. Para *arrays* associativos usa-se `=>`.

Comment: Errata: "Não existe no PHP" quando o contexto é *array*. Existe quando tratado de objetos.

Comment: Dito isso e considerando o fato que o erro ocorreu em um arquivo de uma biblioteca de terceiro, `sendgrid/sendgrid`, diria que não bastará você corrigir a sintaxe no arquivo. Se deu erro por incompatibilidade de sintaxe é porque você está utilizando bibliotecas incompatíveis com a versão instalada (ou vice-versa). O ideal é atualizar o PHP para uma versão que satisfaça todas as suas dependências.

Answer (score 1):

Se a versão do PHP for inferior a 5.4, a declaração curta do array não irá funcionar, pois esse recurso foi adicionado na versão 5.4.0. Além disso, a atribuição de um valor para uma chave de um array deve ser feita utilizando o símbolo `=>`. O símbolo `->` é utilizado para acessar propriedades e/ou métodos de um objeto.

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return array_filter(array(
                'email' => $this->getEmail() //Arrume o símbolo
    ), 'callback');
}
```

Para desencargo de consciência, utilize a forma completa para declarar o array e passe a sua função callback no segundo parâmetro do `array_filter`. Caso funcione, provavelmente o PHP do seu servidor está com uma versão inferior a 5.4.

Comment: Vale citar que como o erro deu em um arquivo de uma biblioteca de terceiro, `sendgrid/sendgrid`, editá-lo não seria a primeira solução. Se deu erro de sintaxe aqui, provavelmente dará em toda a biblioteca e corrigí-la por inteiro provavelmente seria inviável.

Comment: Então conseguir corrigir o erro, então provavelmente que meu serv e inferior ao 5.4, sera que eu teria alguma outra solução, alem de atualiza-o serv, pois ele e antigo o sistema nele ta tudo com linguagem php inferior estamos trabalhando em um novo mais não posso usa-lo por enquanto

Comment: O ideal seria utilizar bibliotecas que possuam compatibilidade com a versão do PHP de seu servidor.